# python binning the Numbers in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to bin an array in the following way:
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... 1.0].

I already try:

```
bins = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9])
Digitalized_lables_train = np.digitize(lables_train, bins )
```

lables_train are numbers from 0-9.

But after this operation i still get bins between 1-10.

Comment: `np.digitize` returns indices, what result do you expect?

Comment: Oh i see my mistake. I want to get the results, that for example [0.783, 0.94, 0.23 ...] transform to [0.7, 0.9, 0.2, ...]. Another solution could have been rounding the numbers to the first figure behind the ".".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

just dividing my `np.digitize(lables_train, bins )` with 10.

But for the case to bin in other float numbers i would like to know which other ways there could be.

Answer (score 1):

As `np.digitize` returns the indices of the bins to which each value in input array belongs you can then collect bin values by those indices with [`np.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```
bins = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9])
lables_train = [0.783, 0.94, 0.23, 0.55, 0.785]  # sample

ltrain_bin_values = np.take(bins, np.digitize(lables_train, bins) - 1)
print(ltrain_bin_values)
```

---

```
[0.7 0.9 0.2 0.5 0.7]
```